# What is wrong with this method of checking for an internet connection?

Tags: ios, objective-c, networking

While looking for a simple asynchronous method to check for internet access in iOS, I had an idea, using a UIWebView to handle asynchronicity:

```
-(void) testNet
{
    UIWebView *webview = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];
    webview.delegate=self;
    NSString *urlAddress = @"http://bla.com/dummySmallFile.txt";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
   [webview loadRequest:requestObj];
}
-(void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    //deal with no net stuff here
}
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    //net is there, use it here
}
```

This seems to be working, but I wanted to know if there are any hidden dangers I might not be aware of in this approach. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you specifically trying to check for access to that site, or Internet access in general?

Comment: Just checking for an existing internet connection. The site might be google or anything reliable, but I'm currently using my own with a small file to minimize the load.

Comment: Why not use what most people use - `Reachability`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two drawbacks to this approach, but there's not much to be done:

1. Data Use: On a device using cellular data, you are using data. If the file is small enough it shouldn't be noticible, but it's still there.
2. If you are checking for Internet access in general, and not just for that site, if that site is down, your app will assume that the Internet is down. This can be mitigated by running the check service on high availability cloud servers, or by using very high availability websites.

Comment: @Yazanalhoroub: #1 matters much less than #2. #2 is a real issue.

Comment: Definitely. I was going for "what if I test the first time with that, then if it fails I try google just to be sure ...", but that approach had its uses for my initial testing purposes, and its time has come :) Many thanks.